# Exception for pip upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to upgrade pip and keep getting this message:

```
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 21.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    (base) name-MBP:~ name$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 244, in run
        wheel_cache = WheelCache(options.cache_dir, options.format_control)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cache.py", line 186, in __init__
        self._ephem_cache = EphemWheelCache(format_control)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cache.py", line 164, in __init__
        self._temp_dir.create()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py", line 73, in create
        tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="pip-{}-".format(self.kind))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 356, in mkdtemp
        prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 126, in _sanitize_params
        dir = gettempdir()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 294, in gettempdir
        tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 229, in _get_default_tempdir
        dirlist)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/var/folders/40/vdlxclg51vjf1q5y8ygtbb840000gn/T/', '/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/Users/name']
```

Even when I am un/installing any thirty party packages (e.g. numpy) i am getting this exception.

Comment: This error often occurs when your temporary directories are full, make sure you don't have cached updates in those folders for example